# Infinite Loop when comparing a number in 2d array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, infinite-loop

Trying to write a function that sees if the number in the array is increasing or decreasing compared to the previous.

Getting an infinite loop.

```
for(int col=0; col < 5; col++) {
    newArray[col][0] = printthis[col][0];
    for(int row = 2; row < 5; row++) {
        cout << col << "\t" << row << "\n";
        if(stoi(printthis[col][row]) > stoi(printthis[col][--row])) {
            newArray[col][row] = "Up";    
        }
        else {
            newArray[col][row] = "Down";    
        } //if else            
    }//inner loop
}
```

Comment: 1st of all fix your formatting please. Next step: Provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Thanks πάντα ῥεῖ I will read that over. Do you have a suggestion for a style guide?

Comment: I'm going to edit to fix your formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the loop index is decreased, so it will always stay at value `2`, note the `--row`:

```
if(stoi(printthis[col][row]) > stoi(printthis[col][--row])){
```

You probably want:

```
if(stoi(printthis[col][row]) > stoi(printthis[col][row-1])){
```

Also the loop should probably start at `row = 1` instead of `2`, to compare to the first row instead of second.

Comment: yes that fixed it. I am just studying C++ I knew it must have been something super NOOB. Thank you, tons.